# New repository, production problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, capistrano

I have a problem with the deployment of the project on the production server. We use Capistrano and Passenger. The problem is that we moved the project repository on GitHub to another account. I changed the repository address in the file deploy.rb, however, during the 'cap production deploy ", after authentication by the production server, Capistrano is looking for an old repository, which fails. I suspect that this is a change in the repository. git on production, but I do not know how to do it.

```
servers: ["85.xxx.xxx.xxx"]
Password:
 [85.xxx.xxx.xx] executing command
** [85.xxx.xxx.xx:: err] ERROR: repo / repo.git does not exist. Did you enter it correctly?
** [85.xxx.xxx.xx:: err] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
 command finished in 4220ms
*** [deploy: update_code] rolling back
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try editing `shared/cached-copy/.git/config` and modify the git repo listed there. If you're using the `remote_cache` method, it keeps a local git repo and updates that on the remote machine. Repoint that to your new git repo and you should be good to go.